# Redirect users based on custom field

Tags: custom-field, users, redirect, buddypress

I'm a novice at Wordpress and i'm pretty sure what i'm looking for is really easy.
I have an issue with a function that doesn't work :

```
    function user_homepage() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'field'   => 25,
            );
      $user_homepage = bp_profile_field_data( $args );

            if ($user_homepage == 'Sports') {
                $redirect_to = home_url('/sports/');
                wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
                exit;
            }

            else if ($user_homepage == 'Tech') {
                $redirect_to = home_url('/tech/');
                wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
                exit;
            }

    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect','user_homepage',10,3);
```

**Updated version, still doesn't work**

```
function redirect_user_homepage() {

        global $bp;

        if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
            $args = array(
                'field'   => 25,
                'user_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id()
                );
          $user_homepage = bp_profile_field_data($args);

                if ($user_homepage == "All") {
                    wp_redirect( home_url() );
                    exit;
                }

                elseif ($user_homepage == "Sports") {
                    wp_redirect( home_url('/sports/') );
                    exit;
                }

                elseif ($user_homepage == "Tech") {
                    wp_redirect( home_url('/tech/') );
                    exit;
                }
        }
    }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_user_homepage');
```

As you can see i want to redirect my users based on a custom field i created in Buddypress. But more than that i don't want them to simply be redirected after login, i want them to be redirect to this page when they go to the website homepage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to update this topic. I've fixed my problem.
Thanks again for the help!

Here's what worked for me:

```
/**
 * Redirect users to their personalized homepage
 */
function peechaya_user_homepage() {

    global $bp;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {

        if ( function_exists( 'bp_profile_field_data' ) ) {
                    $args = array(
                'field'   => 25,
                'user_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id()
                        );
            $user_homepage = bp_get_profile_field_data( $args );
        }

        if ( isset( $user_homepage ) ) {
            if ( $user_homepage === 'All' ) {
                /* Default action */
            }
            elseif ( $user_homepage === 'Tech' ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/tech/' ) );
                exit;
            }
            elseif ( $user_homepage === 'Sports' ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/sports/' ) );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'peechaya_user_homepage' );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your functions, if you want to redirect users when they are visiting the website's homepage. You could implement the [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function to detect and only redirects if they are on the frontpage.

```
function user_homepage() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'field'   => 25,
        );

        $user_homepage = bp_profile_field_data( $args );

        if ( is_front_page() ) {

            if ($user_homepage == 'Sports') {
                $redirect_to = home_url('/sports/');
                wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
                exit;
            }

            else if ($user_homepage == 'Tech') {
                $redirect_to = home_url('/tech/');
                wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect','user_homepage',10,3);
```

Comment: Right! I didn't think of this function, thanks! Now i just have to figure out why the redirection is not happening...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need two SEPARATE but SIMILAR functions. I have never used BuddyPress, so I have to guess that returns a string based on how your logic was written.

I tested this on a nearly new WordPress install and it worked for me by manually setting the `$user_homepage` variable as a default since I did not have BuddyPress installed. The `function_exists` helps protect against issues when the plugin is deactivated or missing.

A quick look at the `bp_profile_field_data` tells me it excepts a field name, so I would use that over a field id. It also implied it could/would get the current user so it probably doesn't need a `user_id`.

Happy coding.

Successful Login Redirect

```
/**
 * Redirect Users to Their Home Page Upon Successful Log in
 */
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_url, $request, $user ) {

    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        $user_homepage = null;

        if ( function_exists( 'bp_profile_field_data' ) ) {
            $user_homepage = bp_profile_field_data( array(
                'field' => 'Field Name',
            ) );
        }

        if ( isset( $user_homepage ) ) {
            if ( $user_homepage === 'Sports' ) {
                $redirect_url = home_url( '/sports/' );
            }
            elseif ( $user_homepage === 'Tech' ) {
                $redirect_url = home_url( '/tech/' );
            }
        }
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Logged in User Front Page Redirect

```
/**
 * Redirect Users to Their Home Page When Hitting the Front Page
 */
function my_template_redirect() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
        $user_homepage = null;

        if ( function_exists( 'bp_profile_field_data' ) ) {
            $user_homepage = bp_profile_field_data( array(
                'field' => 'Field Name',
            ) );
        }

        if ( isset( $user_homepage ) ) {
            if ( $user_homepage === 'Sports' ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/sports/' ) );
                exit;
            }
            elseif ( $user_homepage === 'Tech' ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/tech/' ) );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You're right i should use `function_exists` to prevent issues. Unfortunately even with manually setting `$user_homepage` the redirection is still not happening and i checked all my `wp-redirect` and nothing seems to be in conflict so i have no clue of why it doesn't work...

Comment: If you manually set it after `$user_homepage = null;` AND the `bp_profile_field_data` `function_exists` than that will overwrite the manually set value; My thought is that perhaps  `$user_homepage` returns a different value than you are expecting. Try debugging `$user_homepage` and make sure your if conditions `Sports` and `Tech` are accurate. (It could be a lowercase/uppercase issue)
...
Try to debug the `$user_homepage` before `if ( isset( $user_homepage ) ) {`
...
`printf( "\n<pre class=\"debug\">\n%s\n</pre>\n", var_export( $user_homepage, true ) );`